# What is a good way to check for collisions between the objects in an array?

Tags: objective-c, ios, arrays, game-physics, physics-engine

I have been doing a for loop inside another for loop in order to get 2 objects from the array at the same time, but there must be a better way. I just want to check if they collide to then remove them from the view and array.

Comment: Do you want to remove duplicate items from array?

Comment: Question is unclear, try to rephrase.

Comment: When you say "collide" are you talking about a game where the items in the array have a position in physical space? Or points on a map? Or Items that are the same (i.e. duplicates)?

Comment: Its a game that has UIImageViews in an NSMutableArray and I just want to check when they collide.

Comment: could you please explain about "collide"

Comment: What I mean by collide is when the CGRect of 2 or more objects in an array touch.

Answer (score 5):

You've used the word `collide` in your question without telling us what you meant - that's why the other answers so far aren't helping :) They're talking about collide as in 'duplicate items in a dictionary/array' but you mean collide as in `overlay on the screen`.

This is possibly the worst way of doing this test - it will rapidly become far too slow when you get lots of images. I can't help but think that you're trying to solve a problem that's already been solved by people far smarter than either of us - what *exactly* are you trying to do - maybe a full physics engine might be a better way of achieving your end goal?

For example, take a look at the [spatial hash data structure used by chipmunk](http://chipmunk-physics.net/release/ChipmunkLatest-Docs/#cpSpace-SpatialHash) - this will create a tree containing all your objects - objects which aren't in the same leaves of the tree can't collide so you can reduce your comparisons quickly. However, that link has some diagrams that explain the principle better than I can here :)

If you haven't already, you could try this to optimise the inner loop :

```
// Compare each image with the others to see if they overlap
NSMutableSet *colliding = [NSMutableSet new];
for (NSInteger indexA = 0; indexA < myImages.count; ++indexA) {
    UIView *a = [myImages objectAtIndex:indexA];
    CGRect rectA = a.frame;

    for (NSInteger indexB = indexA; indexB < myImages.count; ++indexB) {
        UIView *b = [myImages objectAtIndex:indexB];
        if (a==b) continue;

        CGRect rectB = b.frame;
        CGRect intersection = CGRectIntersect(rectA, rectB);
        if (NO == CGRectIsNull(intersection)) {
            [colliding addObject:a];
            [colliding addObject:b];
        }
    }
}

// Remove the colliding images
for (UIView *c in colliding) {
    [c removeFromSuperview];
    [myImages removeObject:c];
}
```

Comment: CGRectContainsRect is not correct for a collision detection, CGRectIntersection must be used. Also the internal loop must start from the view next to the external loop's current iteration step.

Comment: Oops, you're absolutely right - I've changed my answer, thanks!

Comment: Thanks,I didnt know collision had another meaning. I am doing it very similar to what you posted. Its not a very good way to do it specially if you want to check more than 2 intersections at the same time and you have a lot of views like me. If I dont find a better way I will stick to cocos2d and its physics engine. Thanks btw.

Comment: Yea, collision to computer scientists means this : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collision_(computer_science) :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for a way to find objects that are in two different arrays at the same time?

If so, I recommend using `indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:` of `NSArray`.

```
@implementation NSArray (Comparison)
- (NSIndexSet *)indexesOfObjects:(NSArray *)objects {
    return [self indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        return [objects containsObject:obj];
    }];
}
- (NSArray *)objectsCommonWithArray:(NSArray *)array {
    return [self objectsAtIndexes:[self indexesOfObjects:array]];
}
@end
```

Then you can do this:

```
// assuming array1 and array2 exist.
NSArray *commonObjects = [array2 objectsCommonWithArray:array2];
```

Comment: Im sorry if my question isnt clear. I have several UIImageViews in a single array. I just want a way to check when they collide to each other.

Comment: Again, please define "collide".

Comment: What I mean by collide is when the CGRect of 2 or more objects in an array touch.

Comment: I think the verb your'te looking for is intersect or overlap.

Answer (score 0):

`NSArray`s have a `containsObject:` method you can use instead of the inner loop.  But it might be faster (someone should benchmark and see) to put all the objects from one into a set (`[NSSet setWithArray:]`) and loop through the other array, checking whether they're in the set.  Or convert them both and use `intersectSet:` (on a mutable copy). My guess is that the set method would be faster as the arrays got larger but it won't make a difference at the numbers you have.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [NSCountedSet](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCountedSet_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

```
NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"1",@"1",@"0",nil];
NSCountedSet *set = [[NSCountedSet alloc] initWithArray:array];
NSLog(@"%@",set); // (1 [2], 0 [1]) // object 1 is collide 
for(id obj in set)
{
    if ([set countForObject:obj]>1) {
        //collide
    }
}
```